# How to create a type of list from joined entities (tables)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework. Here is my simple problem.

I have a SQL database mapped automatically to ADO .NET Entity Data Mode, I wrote a function

```
public List<table1> GetTable1()    
{
  return ( from t in context.table1 select t).ToList();
}
```

and then I attach the data:

```
List<table> list1 = GetTable1();
GridView1.DataSource = list1;
```

but when I wanted to use joined table1 and table2 in select statement I don't know what type of List to use.

What type should the function return so I could attach it to my GridView? 
My only solution now is to create view on database joining those 2 tables and then update the entity Model, but this might be not very elegant way.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: All the tables have same schema?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Anonimous Type` inside the method where datasource is bound :

```
var list1 = (from t in context.table1 select new { ColumnFromTable1 = "whatever", FromOtherTable = "other" }).ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = list1;
```

Of course, you need to know how to join tables, the key point here is:

```
new { ColumnFromTable1 = "whatever", FromOtherTable = "other" }
```

Comment: Note: a function can not return an anonymous type, so create a new type to return. Or as a bad practice, return Tuple<T1,T2>

Comment: Absolutely right, "inside the method where datasource is bound". Another solution is to use list of dynamic

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to this question: [How to get 2 different values in 2 different tables using c# linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025140/how-to-get-2-different-values-in-2-different-tables-using-c-sharp-linq)

You need to create a new class that can encapsulate the result you want back. That way, you can return the type from your data access layer.