# How to get 2 different values in 2 different tables using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a c# program which has a datagridview 
I want to get values in 2 different tables using linq
I know I can achieved this using sql server stored procedure
But I want to do it in linq so I do not need to update database

Heres my code:

```
public List<InsuranceHeader> GetInsuranceList(int InsuranceHeaderId) 
{
    var getData =(from item in context.InsuranceHeader 
                  join item2 in context.InsuranceDetail
                  on item.InsuranceHeaderId equals item2.InsuranceDetailId
                  where item.InsuranceHeaderId == InsuranceHeaderId
                  select item).ToList();

    return getData;
}
```

The other problem is when im returning a value in InsuranceDetail The system throws an error
because I know that I assigned my return type as a List(InsuranceHeader) is there anyway
to achieve this? sorry for my english

Comment: This is not C# code. Please update the sample.

Comment: `"on item.InsuranceHeaderId = item2.InsuranceDetailId"` use `equals` if you join two tables.

Comment: I already edit the code I want to this function to return list of values in InsuranceHeader and InsuranceDetail

Comment: I wouldn't return it as a List, but as a IEnumerable<InsuranceHeader>, and whats the use of joining a detail table? only to get headers which has children?

Comment: `select SomeType(item,item2)` Encapsulate required properties to new type

Comment: I have a form that has a search function which need to view the header and the detail values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new class for it, because a method cannot return an *Anonymous* type.

like:

```
public class InsuranceWithDetail
{
    public InsuranceHeader InsuranceHeader { get; set; }
    public InsuranceDetail InsuranceDetail { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<InsuranceWithDetail> GetInsuranceList(int InsuranceHeaderId) 
{
    var results = from item in context.InsuranceHeader 
                  join item2 in context.InsuranceDetail
                     on item.InsuranceHeaderId equals item2.InsuranceDetailId
                  where item.InsuranceHeaderId == InsuranceHeaderId
                  select new InsuranceWithDetail 
                  { 
                      InsuranceHeader = item, 
                      InsuranceDetail = item2 
                  };

    // storing the results in a variable, will help on debugging. (quick watch)
    return results;
}
```

Also i would return an IEnumerable, because then the query is only executed on demand. The ToList() will iterate **all** items. If you only request `GetInsuranceList(1).FirstOfDefault()` only the **first** iteration is executed. (unless you use orderby etc.)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen your query works great and I have learn a different approach thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I used the solution from previous post.
Unfortunately, I couldn't attach it to my GridView.
On DataBind():

```
 GridView1.DataSource = GetInsuranceList();
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

i got:

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is
>   not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by
>   calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind
>   to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().

I added ToList() at the end of GetInsuranceList()

```
public IEnumerable<InsuranceWithDetail> GetInsuranceList(int InsuranceHeaderId) 
{
    var results = (from item in context.InsuranceHeader 
                  join item2 in context.InsuranceDetail
                     on item.InsuranceHeaderId equals item2.InsuranceDetailId
                  where item.InsuranceHeaderId == InsuranceHeaderId
                  select new InsuranceWithDetail 
                  { 
                      InsuranceHeader = item, 
                      InsuranceDetail = item2 
                  }).ToList;

    return results;
}
```

Now I get from DataBind():

> The data source for GridView  did not have any properties or
>   attributes from which to generate columns